# Excel Pivot Table - How to show custom selection of categories as proportion of grand total

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm struggling to structure my pivot table or input data in order to allow users to select a custom grouping of `Categories` (using a slicer), and then show that `Selection` as a proportion of the grand total. I've created an example in this file which can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zv0yzzopyi7bfym337ss9/Dummy-Pivot.xlsx?dl=1), illustrated below.

- I want users to create their custom `Selection` using the slicer
  buttons, as in Pivot 1. In this case the user wants to compare
  `Categories` `A` and `B` combined into a single `Selection`.
- I've mocked up what I want to see over on the right in the red box: a pivot table showing both the `Selection`, the `Grand Total` for all `Categories`, and the % which is `Selection` divided by `Grand Total`
- How can I create a true sortable dynamic pivot table (rather than the mock lookup table in red) that allows a user to create a custom aggregation of categories and express that as a % of the total? Is there a way to combine two pivot tables and have them dynamically refresh?

[image: Screenshot of Scenario]